# Is is possible to include a source file in nodejs+puppeteer to add functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I know

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(fs.readFileSync('./helperFunctions.js', 'utf8'));
```

to add functions to `evaluate()` context, that is very handy.

But is anyone can provide any example to have the same on the main context ? By example, said I want to add a

```
page.existsText()
```

or

```
existsText()
```

function with this code **from a file to be included/sourced** :

```
existsText = (string) => {
    // code goes here
}
```

What is the way to go ?

Comment: So you would like a way to use same code from a fike maybe, in both contexts?

Comment: No, a file for `evaluate()` context and another one to the _main_ context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your *intention* correctly, you would like to *import functions from a file into global namespace*, without having to assign them to an intermediary variable. Here's a simple way to do this in node.

**helperFunctions.js**

```
(function(){
    // Assign the function to the scope from where it's called
    this.existsText = (string) => {
        console.log("Do stuff with " + string);
    }
})()
```

Then when your require it in node.js/puppeteer script it executes at once assigning functions from it to global scope:

```
require("./helperFunctions");

existsText("global scope");
```

Result:

> Do stuff with global scope

---

**Bonus**: using the same functions in page.evaluate

If needed the same helper file can then be used in browser scope:

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(fs.readFileSync('./helperFunctions.js', 'utf8'));

await page.evaluate(() => { 
    existsText("browser scope");
});
```

> Do stuff with browser scope

Answer (score 1):

You can add some methods of the Page class from the page object for quick hacking.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // page constructor is Page, 
  // and we can add some other methods to it's prototype
  page.constructor.prototype.myCustomMethod = function() {
    return this._frameManager.mainFrame().url();
  };

  await page.goto("https://example.com");
  const customUrl = await page.myCustomMethod();

  console.log({ customUrl }); // Returns { customUrl: 'https://example.com/' }
  await browser.close();
});
```

It's as simple as that for some quick hacks. So, let's add some `exists` method to that.

```
// get all arguments
page.constructor.prototype.existsText = function(...args) {
  // let's assume the argument as a variable called string
  return this._frameManager.mainFrame().evaluate(string => {
    // create a new regex to find global multiline insensitive results
    const searchRegex = new RegExp(string, "gmi");
    // find all matchs
    return document.querySelector("body").outerHTML.match(searchRegex);
  }, args); // pass all arguments
};
const foundText = await page.existsText("more");
console.log({ foundText }); 
// Result: { foundText: [ 'More' ] }
```

Again, these are all quick hacks and have their own limitation. Feel free to explore.

Comment: The point is to include/import/require **from an external file** as pointed in the title itself  ^^

Comment: well just import/require/include it and assign it ;)

Comment: I would like to export functions to the global scope or the `page` context, without having to do `var x = require('foobar); x.ownFunction()`